# How to create a custom GET method that matches a certain URL pattern?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using a `DefaultRouter` and have a custom method in it. Right now I am passing values as POST but I want to pass as GET with the pattern like `example.com/wallets/balance/<customerID>/`. I am using ViewSet.

My current `urls.py` looks like:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('wallets', views.WalletView, basename='WalletModel')
router.register('wallets/balance/1/', views.custom_balance,basename='CustomBalanceModel') # This crashes
```

and `models.py`

```
def custom_balance(id):
    return Response({'status': 'OK', 'data': 'success'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

class WalletView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  .....
```

Answer (score 0):

When I did this I used a .js file to do the `get` and `post`

Something like this to get *all* data. Then I passed it to the template using AngularJS.

You could do this in an [AJAX .get call](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp) in the  tag inside the template as well if you're not using AngularJS or VueJS for example.

```
    function HeatTreatController($scope, $http) {


        $scope.Foodata =[];
        var q
        $http.get('/wallets/balance/').then(function(response){
            $scope.Foodata = response.data;
            $scope.Fooworkorder = response.data.workOrder;
        });

}
```

`Foodata` would then be everything sent by your `serializer` through the viewset.
`workorder` is just the `workOrder` value (`models.py` workOrder field) accessed by the dot operator. Just like when you have a `QuerySet` and you want to get sub fields of your model.

`wallets/balance` has to be an accesible API URL.
In your Django app you should be able to go to this URL and see the data.

Now if you want to get 1 specific piece of data from a GET

```
    function FooController($scope, $http) {


        $scope.Foodata =[];
        var q
        $http.get('/wallets/balance/'+customer.id +'/').then(function(response){
            $scope.Foodata = response.data;
            $scope.workorder = response.data.workOrder;
        });

}
```

If I am understanding your question correctly it would not be strictly necessary to separate URL like `router.register('wallets/balance/1/', views.custom_balance,basename='CustomBalanceModel')`.
You can `GET` and `POST` through `router.register('wallets', views.WalletView, basename='WalletModel')`

Here is some more Django documentation on [ViewSets](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/)

So in this cast if you're already doing a `POST` request somehow in your code you can instead do a `GET` request in the same fashion.

If you have the time to learn, I learned all this from Pluralsight:
https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/django-angularjs-web-development
If you have a day or two you can learn it all.

I also recommend this [Max Goodridge video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zcJegVlKqqs&t=195s). They're all pretty good